# ALSA playback interrupted without snd_pcm_hw_params_get_* calls

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm finding that a simple ALSA playback program behaves differently when I put in some calls to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_*` functions.  My program plays a sine wave from a buffer repeatedly.  When I include the calls, I get a pure tone as I expected.  When I remove the calls, however, I get a series of beeps.  This worries me, because I would not expect calls that retrieve data to have anything to do with how the sound is played.  I get this behavior both on a cheap USB sound card and my (presumably nicer) internal sound card.

Here is the code:

```
#define GETPARAMS


int main() {
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  const char name[] = "hw:0,0";

  int dir;

  snd_pcm_stream_t stream = SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK;
  snd_pcm_access_t access = SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED;
  snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
  unsigned int rate = 48000;
  unsigned int channels = 2;
  unsigned int periods = 4;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t periodsize = 2048;
  int num_frames = 2*periodsize;


  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
  snd_pcm_open(&handle, name, stream, 0);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

#ifdef GETPARAMS
  printf("\nparameters before setting:\n");
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &rate, &dir);
  printf("  rate = %d, dir = %d\n", rate, dir);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &channels);
  printf("  channels = %d\n", channels);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods(params, &periods, &dir);
  printf("  periods = %d, dir = %d\n", periods, dir);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(params, &periodsize);
  printf("  periodsize = %ld\n", periodsize);
#endif

  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, access);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, format);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &rate, &dir);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods(handle, params, periods, 0);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size(handle, params, num_frames);
  snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);

#ifdef GETPARAMS
  printf("\nparameters after setting:\n");
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &rate, &dir);
  printf("  rate = %d, dir = %d\n", rate, dir);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &channels);
  printf("  channels = %d\n", channels);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods(params, &periods, &dir);
  printf("  periods = %d, dir = %d\n", periods, dir);
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(params, &periodsize);
  printf("  periodsize = %ld\n\n", periodsize);
#endif

  int16_t *data = (int16_t*)calloc(2*periodsize, sizeof(int16_t));
  loadpage(data, 2*periodsize);

  snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;
  snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, data, num_frames);
    if (frames < 0)
      frames = snd_pcm_recover(handle, frames, 0);
    if (frames < 0) {
      printf("snd_pcm_writei failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(frames));
    }
    if (frames > 0 && frames < num_frames)
      printf("short write (expected %d, write %li)\n", num_frames, frames);
  }

  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  free(data);
}
```

`loadpage()` fills the buffer.  When I comment out the `#define GETPARAMS` I get a series of short beeps.  When I include it I get a pure tone.

Here is the output when `GETPARAMS` is defined:

```
parameters before setting:
  rate = 48000, dir = 32766
  channels = 2
  periods = 4, dir = 32766
  periodsize = 2048

parameters after setting:
  rate = 48000, dir = 0
  channels = 2
  periods = 4, dir = 0
  periodsize = 4096
```

Comment: Check for errors after every function call.

Comment: I have.  I took out the checks to reduce the size of the code before I posted it.  Even if I did or did not get errors, I'm still puzzled.  Why should the behavior of the code rely on getting data before and after setting parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You must not call the `snd_pcm_hw_param_get_*()` functions if the parameters have not yet been set because at that time, the configuration space contains multiple potential values for the parameters.

To print the current state of the `hw_params` container, use `snd_pcm_hw_params_dump()`:

```c
snd_output_t *output;

snd_output_stdio_attach(&output, stdout, 0);

...

snd_pcm_hw_params_dump(params, output);

...

snd_output_close(output);
```

Anyway, the problem is that the initial values of `periods`, `periodsize`, and `num_frames` are inconsistent, and that the `_get_` calls overwrite these variables with other values that happen to be consistent.

I do not know what values you actually want to use, but note that the period size and the buffer size are measured in frames, and that one frame contains all samples of all channels, i.e., in this case, one frame has four bytes.